# htaccess redirect with parameters not working

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite, redirect

I'm struggling with an Apache rewriterule. I need to do the following:

Redirect permanently:

http://domain.com/folder/viewer/data/settings.xml?prevent_cache=4760

to

http://domain.com/siteid/includes/themes/siteid/swfs/viewer/data/settings.xml?prevent_cache=4760

I've got the code below, it works without the url parameters but I can't seem to get it to work with parameters. Am i missing something?

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^prevent_cache=([0-9]*)$
RewriteRule ^/folder/viewer/data/settings.xml$ http://domain.com/siteid/includes/themes/siteid/swfs/viewer/data/settings.xml [R=301,L]
```

Cheers

Shaun

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only error I can see, is the leading slash `/` in the `RewriteRule` pattern. This should be

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^prevent_cache=[0-9]*$
RewriteRule ^folder/viewer/data/settings.xml$ /siteid/includes/themes/siteid/swfs/viewer/data/settings.xml [R,L]
```

You don't need to append the query string to the substitution URL, because this is done autmoatically.

When everything works as you expect, you can change `R` to `R=301`. Never test with `301` enabled, see this answer [Tips for debugging .htaccess rewrite rules](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9204355/1741542) for details.

Answer (score 0):

I can. Here are the rewrite condition and rule that you're looking for:

```
# once per htaccess file
RewriteEngine on

RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} prevent_cache=([0-9]*)
RewriteRule ^folder/viewer/data/settings.xml http://domain.com/siteid/includes/themes/siteid/swfs/viewer/data/settings.xml?prevent_cache=%1 [R=301,L]
```

But please considered this answer about the *[R=301]* flag: https://stackoverflow.com/a/15999177/2007055