# Remove string from URL using .htaccees

Tags: string, .htaccess, url, mod-rewrite, bit.ly

I've set up a bit.ly link and printed it on 1000 flyers.
Somehow the bit.ly target link contains some strings which shouldn't be there (https://example.com/page/%E2%80%8E instead of https://example.com/page/)

Can I get rid of this string using rewrite rules in `.htaccess`?

Any help is appreciated!

Comment: Give some sample of the URL that redirect and the original URL where the redirecting URL redirect..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you just accidentally added the string `%20%E2%80%8E` in the creation of the short link, then you can just get another short link without accidentally added the string again.

Anyway, I think these `.htaccess` directives are what you want:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)\%20\%E2\%80\%8E$
RewriteRule ^(.*) https://example.com/%1 [R,L]
```

It will redirect `example.com/$anything%20%E2%80%8E` into `example.com/$anything`

Just make sure that there's Apache HTTP Server with `mod_rewrite` on your web hosting account. And considered this link about the `[R=301]` flag: https://stackoverflow.com/a/15999177/2007055.

---

This code:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)/\%20\%E2\%80\%8E$
RewriteRule ^(.*) https://example.com/%1/ [R,L]
```

Is to redirect `example.com/$anything/%20%E2%80%8E` into `example.com/$anything/`.

Comment: @PhiLieb Please check the updates.