# Htaccess redirection with special chars (%E2%80%8E)

Tags: wordpress, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, redirect

The question is very similar to this, but the accepted answer did not work in our case:

[Remove string from URL using .htaccees](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16173653/remove-string-from-url-using-htaccees)

The website URL we're trying to redirect is the following:

http://www.example.com/fr/sub-folder/%E2%80%8E

The website is running WordPress. We simply want to redirect this url to the base page (http://www.example.com/fr/sub-folder/)

We first tried basic 301:

```
redirect 301 "/fr/sub-folder/%E2%80%8E" http://www.example.com/fr/sub-folder/
```

We tried the following:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)/\%20\%E2\%80\%8E$
RewriteRule ^(.*) http://example.com/fr/sub-folder/%1/ [R,L]
```

This little variation:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)/\%E2\%80\%8E$
RewriteRule ^(.*) http://example.com/fr/sub-folder/%1/ [R,L]
```

But nothing is working.

Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can just use this rule:

```
RewriteRule /\xE2\x80\x8E$ /fr/sub-folder [L,R=302]
```