# Trying to Redirect 301 %E2%80%A6 in htaccess file

Tags: html, .htaccess, redirect

I have a link in my Google Webmaster Tools that is coming from a big website that posted my link incorrectly. With many attempts to get them to change it I am going to 301 the link to the right page because I want that link. Problem is that in my GWT it is showing the link as

http://www.otherdomain.com/%E2%80%A6crabble-word-finder

If you put your mouse over the link it looks like

http://www.otherdomain.com/...crabble-word-finder

I tried in my htaccess file which didn't work

```
Redirect 301 /...crabble-word-finder http://www.mydomain.com/scrabble-word-finder/
```

AND

```
Redirect 301 /%E2%80%A6crabble-word-finder http://www.mydomain.com/scrabble-word-finder/
```

Any idea how to get this redirect to work?

Answer (score 0):

If you just want to redirect */%E2%80%A6crabble-word-finder* into */scrabble-word-finder/* then you can simply try this *.htaccess* code:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^%E2%80%A6crabble-word-finder/?$ /scrabble-word-finder/ [R]
```

Just considered the `[R=301]` flag with this link: https://stackoverflow.com/a/15999177/2007055

Answer (score 0):

some hackers try to use such redirects for exploitation of a site.

If they succeed in redirecting then they try to inject what may seem as an innocuous internal link via forms in order to redirect traffic to their site and/or get link juice a-la page rank.

Answer (score 0):

Try using quotes:

```
Redirect 301 "/...crabble-word-finder" http://www.mydomain.com/scrabble-word-finder/
```