# RewriteRule for htaccess using regex

Tags: regex, .htaccess

I need to redirect /start to /start/index.html and everything else (/anything) to /index.html

What is the correct regex rewriterule for this?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I need to redirect `/start` to `/start/index.html` and everything else (**/anything**) to `/index.html`. What is the correct regex rewriterule for this?

You may try this in one .htaccess file at root directory:

```
Options +FollowSymlinks -MultiViews
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI}  !index\.html      [NC]
RewriteRule ^start/(.*)  /start/index.html?$1 [L,NC,QSA]
```

In the rule, `anything` is passed as a query to `index.php` and the QSA flag adds the incoming one when present.

To pass `anything` as a path segment, replace `?$1` with `/$1` and remove the QSA flag. It's useless, as any incoming query will be appended automatically.

For permanent redirection, replace [L,NC,QSA] with [R=301,L,NC,QSA]

Answer (score 1):

Rewrite condition is needed:

```
RewriteRule ^start/?$ /start/index.html [R]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/start/?$
RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)/?$ /index.html [R]
```

Please considered this link about the `[R]` flag: https://stackoverflow.com/a/15999177/2007055