# https rewrite or redirect in a shared hosting environment

Tags: apache, .htaccess

My web host is hostgator.com with Apache, cPanel, etc.

A spammer somewhere has set links to my site somewhere, using https in the URL. I don't have an SSL certificate and would expect these links to resolve to the error 404 page.

However the links cause Firefox to say my domains are attack sites, due to their hookup with Google safe browsing.

Hostgator support is slow and clueless. Links are in the following format.

```
https://mydomainname.com/
https://mydomainname.com/digital-photography-forum-uk/
https://mydomainname.com/fastibl/
https://mydomainname.com/search-engine-marketing/
https://mydomainname.com/search-engine-optimisation/
https://mydomainname.com/website-programming-discussion/
```

I've edited .htaccess a dozen times, using online examples of redirecting https to http and nothing (yet) works.

Answer (score 1):

Just try these configuration directives in your *.htaccess* file:

```
Options +FollowSymlinks
RewriteEngine on

RewriteCond %{HTTPS} on
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://mydomainname.com/$1 [R=301,L]
```

But please considered the `[R=301]` flag with this link: https://stackoverflow.com/a/15999177/2007055

Or try to use a *robots.txt* file if it can block or remove the pages in HTTPS on search engines. And if any of those solutions did not work, then you've better purchase an SSL certificate to solve your problem.

Comment: Hostgator telephoned me in response to a Chat inquiry. Stating that in a shared hosting environment RewriteCond %{HTTPS} won't work. HTTPS requests are processed higher up in the architecture, grabbing the first SSL certificate on that IP address regardless of who it belongs to and given that I don't have an SSL certificate. Dedicated IP address is the work around, or moving to VPS. Can't believe they actually telephoned me when the Ticket system failed to produce results. Great response from Hostgator though it did take me awhile to locate someone with the definitive answer.